# Return all months, including ones not on the table i am extracting information from

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a query that has the history of number of messages sent from different units grouped by month. However, not all units sent messages on every single month, and this query only shows the months where messages were sent. I would like to alter the query so that the months where messages were not sent appears in the result, can someone please help me? I appreciate any help or links to other similar questions (none I found helped me).

```
SELECT substring(tags.name from 6) as "Unit"
  , date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at)) as "Date"
  , count(distinct(messages.id)) as "Messages"

FROM messages
  LEFT JOIN contracts on messages.from_id = contracts.id
  LEFT JOIN contracts_tags on contracts.id = contracts_tags.contract_id
  LEFT JOIN tags on contracts_tags.tag_id = tags.id

WHERE messages.company_id = 72
  AND messages.state = 'sent'
  AND tags.name like '%Unit:%'

GROUP BY substring(tags.name from 6), date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at))

ORDER BY substring(tags.name from 6), date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at))
```

Below is a query that returns a list of all the months I want this query to show. I think this might help you help me!

```
SELECT date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at)) 
FROM messages 
WHERE messages.sent_at > '2016-10-01'
GROUP BY date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at)) 
ORDER BY date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at))
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the more elegant way to write the query, but it should get the job done.

```
SELECT b.Unit, a.Date, COALESCE(b.Messages, 0)

FROM
(SELECT date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at)) as "Date"
FROM messages 
WHERE messages.sent_at > '2016-10-01'
GROUP BY date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at)) 
ORDER BY date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at))
) AS a

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT substring(tags.name from 6) as "Unit"
  , date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at)) as "Date"
  , count(distinct(messages.id)) as "Messages"

FROM messages
  LEFT JOIN contracts on messages.from_id = contracts.id
  LEFT JOIN contracts_tags on contracts.id = contracts_tags.contract_id
  LEFT JOIN tags on contracts_tags.tag_id = tags.id

WHERE messages.company_id = 72
  AND messages.state = 'sent'
  AND tags.name like '%Unit:%'

GROUP BY substring(tags.name from 6), date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at))

ORDER BY substring(tags.name from 6), date(date_trunc('month',messages.sent_at))
) as b
  ON a.Date = b.Date
```

A simple left join should do it. The coalesce is to add a zero's in the Messages columns because there will be nulls otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that but I tried it again with your code. Unfortunately, it didn't work :( .. Thanks @users3264602